# Password Manager for SharePoint

Tags: workflow, permissions

Recently my company asked me to search for a **Password Manager**. Right now some of the employees save their passwords in .txt files on the Desktop. This is - obviously - not very safe.

So instead of having their passwords on their PC we would like the passwords to be stored on our Server and can be accessed through *SharePoint*. The users should also be in groups so a system for that would be nice. So let's say an employee works in work group A and should therefore have only access to their passwords while another on from work group B should just have the passwords needed for B. But the manager of both groups should have all passwords.

I don't know if there is a way to this in SharePoint. If not, please suggest another system that can run on our Server and maybe also be accessible through Browser. If its with a Client it's no problem, but Browser access would be the best. Also saving the data on an external Server is not an option.

Last information: we need a good and stable system, because I work in a company with >700 employees and errors would be fatal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, you could create lists in order to achieve that. For example, you create 2 lists, A and B, grant permissions to some users to the list A and some to the list B. In the manager's case, you grant permissions to both lists, the items in those lists are the username/password. Also, it is nice that you can grant users read-only access so only users with more privileges would be able to add/manage passwords.

If the solution above is not exactly what you are looking for, I would let you know about [SECRET SERVE](https://thycotic.com/products/secret-server/). I have not used but looking at it, this software looks very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not good fit for the SharePoint. You have to use the 3rd party software to manage the password.

In past we used the [PAR tool](http://software.dell.com/products/privileged-password-manager/) from Dell (old Quest).

Reason why SharePoint is not fit.

- Once user get the password, then User dont need to come back and get it. as SharePoint will not change the password.
- You have to manually change the Password
- You have to apply alot of customization in order to protect the accounts from non-eligible user.